# Django filter sub elements in single query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django DRF project tracking students in classes at a school. There are `teacher`s, `student`s, `administration`, and `school_class`es. Not all students are verified, but administration should see all students while teachers should only see verified students.

It's simple enough to make a queryset so when teachers query for students, they only get back verified students. But the problem comes when a teacher queries a class and goes to access `school_class.students`. Here it will list out all the students, whether or not they are verified. How can I have the students list filtered in the same query that fetches the class?

Comment: can you post all your models in question?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the serializer with a method field.

```
    students = SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    def get_students(self, obj):
        """
        Administration sees everyone, teachers see only verified.
        """

        if self.context['request'].user.type == 'teacher':
            qs = obj.students.filter(verified=True)
        elif self.context['request'].user.type == 'administration':
            qs = obj.students
        return qs
```